# Running Commands every 5 minutes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a licensing system for my script. I want to check if there's a license every 5 minutes.

I have added my `licensechecker.sh` to crontab like this;

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/file/licensechecker.sh
```

But it seems it isn't working. I have tested it with:

```
*/1 * * * * reboot
```

But my VPS didn't reboot.

I have checked logs:

```
Sep 3 15:42:01 eyup CRON[23368]: (root) CMD (reboot) 
Sep 3 15:42:01 eyup CRON[23366]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) 
Sep 3 15:43:01 eyup CRON[23675]: (root) CMD (reboot) 
Sep 3 15:43:01 eyup CRON[23674]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) 
Sep 3 15:44:01 eyup CRON[24023]: (root) CMD (reboot) 
Sep 3 15:44:01 eyup CRON[24022]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) 
Sep 3 15:45:01 eyup CRON[24336]: (root) CMD (reboot)
```

Comment: Is a cron service running on the VPS? Which crontab did you add it to, and how exactly?

Comment: Is cron enabled?  Are you getting errors from your script? Have you looked for cron logs?  Maybe the path isn't set?

Comment: @steeldriver I have written these command; `sudo service cron start` && `sudo systemctl start cron`

Comment: @user10489 It says this; Sep  3 15:42:01 eyup CRON[23368]: (root) CMD (reboot)
Sep  3 15:42:01 eyup CRON[23366]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep  3 15:43:01 eyup CRON[23675]: (root) CMD (reboot)
Sep  3 15:43:01 eyup CRON[23674]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep  3 15:44:01 eyup CRON[24023]: (root) CMD (reboot)
Sep  3 15:44:01 eyup CRON[24022]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep  3 15:45:01 eyup CRON[24336]: (root) CMD (reboot)

Comment: Putting responses in your question is more effective than adding a comment.  Sounds like if you intall an MTA you will get your error log.  At least you know it is running (and getting errors).

Comment: @petep the slash notation is really a *modulo* division i.e. `*/5 * * * *` runs whenever the minute counter is divisible by 5 (i.e. every 5 minutes). Your `* */12 * * *` would run every minute whenever the hour is divisible by 12.

Comment: What operating system is the VPS running? Also, is there a `reboot` command in cron's PATH? What is the output of  `type -a reboot`? Does it work if you use the full path to the reboot command returned by `type`?

Comment: @terdon My vps is running on Ubuntu 18.04LTS, `type -a reboot` output is `/sbin/reboot`, When I type the full path it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Cron doesn't use your user's PATH, [it has its own, hardcoded `$PATH` variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401622/22222) which is set to `/usr/bin:/bin`. So only commands that are stored in one of those two directories can be run by name. For all others, you need the full path to the executable. Since your `reboot` command is in `/sbin`, you need this line:

```
*/1 * * * * /sbin/reboot
```

However, this really isn't a good way of testing since you will have a lot of difficulty removing this line once it works since your machine will be rebooting every minute. You can instead test using a safe command like this:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/date > /tmp/date.log
```

And then just check that the file `/tmp/date.log` is created and the date is printed there every minute.

Comment: How can I make it work for every user since everyone's `$PATH` is different?

Comment: The path of each executable does not change with users - so just use absolute paths for everything.

Comment: @Erikli the user's PATH is irrelevant. Please read the link provided in the answer: cron has its own, hardcoded PATH and ignores any user-specific settings.

Comment: Don't run a reboot every minute or you will have a hard task to recover from this situation...

Comment: Good point, @raj, answer edited.

Comment: I have figured it out to work with it, But now I have this problem; `/root/test.sh: line 2: reboot: command not found` It doesn't see `reboot` as command. I written `#!/bin/bash` in `/root/test.sh` but still the result is same. NOTE: I can't rewrite my script so I'm not going to write `/sbin/reboot`

Comment: @Erikli I have explained why it doesn't see it, that's the whole point of the answer: you need to use the full path. Or you can set `PATH` in the crontab or in the script, but why are you even using `reboot`?

Comment: @terdon I don't, it was just an example to see if crontab will work. I can't set the full path because I'm gonna run binary file on crontab.

Comment: @Erikli so you need the full path to the binary you want to run.